# Certain programs on Lulu app (Objective see) are not filtered

Tags: macos, monterey, firewall

I am finding that certain apps (on Monterey) are not being filtered. These are native apple apps. Even if I disable network access, on reboot, it resets. When I `deny` access, it adds another deny rule. That results in 2 rules, one saying `allow` the other saying `deny`.

This can happen in `pf` like firewalls as well, but `pf` has strict rules on how any line will be evaluated from top to bottom.

How does `lulu` evaluate rules from top to bottom? Will it take the topmost rule and stop evaluating rules at the bottom, for the same program?

P.S. I do see that certain apple programs are not bypassing Lulu and LittleSnitch firewalls: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=24838816

Comment: What kind of research have you already done in this? It somehow looks like a question which can be easily answered by looking at the product documentation or reaching  out to developer/vendor.

Comment: I’m going to answer the main question and set aside the two “bonus” questions tacked on. An edit to this to focus on one specific app and one specific version of lulu might get a more detailed answer.

Comment: Ok, I will narrow this down and open another thread.

Answer (score 2):

If Apple doesn’t pass their traffic through the network extension that LuLu uses, then you are correct.

The FAQ doesn’t address this directly, but I seem to recall the author calling out a few notable exceptions in a talk recently but don’t see details posted publicly on specifics.

If you have some, opening an issue (see GitHub link at the end of the FAQ) might get you a more authoritative confirmation of this.

- https://objective-see.org/products/lulu.html

The allow rule for all signed Apple apps is a recent feature, so if you’re on LuLu v 1.2.0 you could try disabling the signed Apple app check box and perhaps have better blocking ( and likely some breakage of functions in the OS too ).

- https://github.com/objective-see/LuLu/issues/97#issuecomment-466268797